# How can I fix this VBA code to remove duplicates and drag formulas down?

Tags: excel, vba

I am pretty new to VBA and my code is probably a mess and that's why it is not working. But I am not able to fix it, hours of googling and nothing. It works fine till comment Select and copy. It copies data to sheet "LSMW ZVOL MATERIAL". But sometimes it pastes it with two extra blank rows on top (it copies filtered data, there is no blank rows). Section with comment Remove duplicates and Drag formukas is also not working.

What I am also trying to achieve with it is that after it sets filters in sheet SUM, it shows a pop-up window with question "Continue?", if user says yes, then it copies filtered data from sheet SUM columns AT3:AW to the last row of data, paste it in sheet "LSMW ZVOL MATERIAL" in cell A4, remove duplicated lines from pasted data and drag formulas from range E5:AA5 to the bottom of pasted data.

If user says no it stops macro. Any ideas how to fix it?

```
 Public Function GetLastRow(Optional Col As Integer = 1, Optional Sheet As Excel.Worksheet)
    If Sheet Is Nothing Then
        Set Sheet = Worksheets("LSMW ZVOL MATERIAL")
    End If
    GetLastRow = Sheet.Cells(Sheet.Rows.Count, Col).End(xlUp).Row
 End Function

Sub PricingTransferZVOL()

    Dim LastRow As Integer

        LastRow = GetLastRow(1, Worksheets("SUM"))
    
    Dim LastRowZVOL As Integer
    
        LastRowZVOL = GetLastRow(1, Worksheets("LSMW ZVOL MATERIAL"))
     
    Dim UsdRw As Integer
    
        UsdRw = GetLastRow(1, Worksheets("LSMW ZVOL MATERIAL"))
        
     
'Delete old data in LSMW ZVOL MATERIAL sheet
    Worksheets("LSMW ZVOL MATERIAL").Rows(7 & ":" & Worksheets("LSMW ZVOL MATERIAL").Rows.Count).Delete
    Worksheets("LSMW ZVOL MATERIAL").range("A4:D6").ClearContents
    
    
'Set filters to ZVOL
    Call Removefilters
    Call ZVOLFilter
    
'Select and copy
    range("AT3:AW" & LastRow).Select
    Selection.Copy Worksheets("LSMW ZVOL MATERIAL").range("A4")
    
'Remove duplicates

    Worksheets("LSMW ZVOL MATERIAL").range("A4:D" & LastRowZVOL).RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1, 2, 3, 4)
    
 'Drag down formulas
 
    Worksheets("LSMW ZVOL MATERIAL").range("E5:AA5").AutoFill _
        Destination:=Worksheets("LSMW ZVOL MATERIAL").range("E5:AA" & UsdRw), _
        Type:=xlFillCopy
 
End Sub'
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Your first part of the question is not clear.
Regarding your second part (asking the user), here is how to do it

```
Public Function GetLastRow(Optional Col As Integer = 1, Optional Sheet As Excel.Worksheet)
    If Sheet Is Nothing Then
        Set Sheet = Worksheets("LSMW ZVOL MATERIAL")
    End If
    GetLastRow = Sheet.Cells(Sheet.Rows.Count, Col).End(xlUp).Row
 End Function


Sub PricingTransferZVOL()

Dim UserAnswer As Integer

    Dim LastRow As Integer

        LastRow = GetLastRow(1, Worksheets("SUM"))
    
    Dim LastRowZVOL As Integer
    
        LastRowZVOL = GetLastRow(1, Worksheets("LSMW ZVOL MATERIAL"))
     
    Dim UsdRw As Integer
    
        UsdRw = GetLastRow(1, Worksheets("LSMW ZVOL MATERIAL"))
        
     
'Delete old data in LSMW ZVOL MATERIAL sheet
    Worksheets("LSMW ZVOL MATERIAL").Rows(7 & ":" & Worksheets("LSMW ZVOL MATERIAL").Rows.Count).Delete
    Worksheets("LSMW ZVOL MATERIAL").range("A4:D6").ClearContents
    
    
'Set filters to ZVOL
    Call Removefilters
    Call ZVOLFilter
 
 'Ask the user if he wants to continue
 'you can change the Continue but whatever text question that you want
 UserAnswer = MsgBox("Continue?", vbQuestion + vbYesNo + vbDefaultButton2, "Continue running the code ? ")
 
 If UserAnswer = vbYes Then
 'Add Your code to filter data etc... if user said Yes
 
'Select and copy
    range("AT3:AW" & LastRow).Select
    Selection.Copy Worksheets("LSMW ZVOL MATERIAL").range("A4")
    
'Remove duplicates

    Worksheets("LSMW ZVOL MATERIAL").range("A4:D" & LastRowZVOL).RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1, 2, 3, 4)
    
 'Drag down formulas
 
    Worksheets("LSMW ZVOL MATERIAL").range("E5:AA5").AutoFill _
        Destination:=Worksheets("LSMW ZVOL MATERIAL").range("E5:AA" & UsdRw), _
        Type:=xlFillCopy
 
    Else
    'The user said No you can add code or Exit Sub
      Exit Sub 'Note that in this case you don't need the exit sub because you are at the end of the sub code, but I put it just to show you how to exit
    End If
 
End Sub
```

Comment: About first part of question. It copies filtered data from SUM without any problem. It is one block of data without blank rows. 

In next step it should paste the data in cell A4 in sheet "LSMW ZVOL MATERIAL". But somehow it pastes 5 lines of data, then makes 8 empty rows and then comes rest of data. It also doesn't remove duplicates at all.

Comment: are you sure that the LastRowZVOL is returning the right value each time? I think you have a problem with that function/value...as for the copy paste, do something like Worksheets("LSMW ZVOL MATERIAL").range("A4:D" & LastRowZVOL).Copy (Worksheets("LSMW ZVOL MATERIAL").range("A4"))